# No listener error when connecting Oracle database to excel

Tags: excel, oracle

I am getting **no listener** error in excel 2013 while trying to connect to Oracle database.I install excel 2013 new addon power query and also install OraClient11g
I.e. Oracle client component.

Comment: You are trying to connect to a server:port where there is no listener. Make sure the listener is up and that you are connecting to the correct server:port

Comment: by sql developer i m not getting any such kind of error.By excel through i m getting NO LISTENER error

Comment: Then find the differences in the connection details between SQL Developer and Excel.